# Account wide Rate Limiting

Tags: yii2

The official Yii docs talk about adding rate limiting to an api by implementing [yii\filters\RateLimitInterface](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-ratelimitinterface) on a [user identity class](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-user#$identityClass-detail).

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-rate-limiting

But is it possible to implement rate limiting on classes that aren't the user class?

For example in my api a User belongs to an Account.
An Account has many Users.

Is it possible to implement rate limiting per Account, rather than per User? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options how to do that.

First option is to implement `RateLimitInterface` in same class that implements `IdentityInterface` but load/store allowance in your account model.
If your `User` model implements `IdentityInterface` and has `Account` relation it can look like this:

```php
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface, RateLimitInterface
{
    public function getRateLimit($request, $action)
    {
        return [$this->account->rateLimit, 1]; // $rateLimit requests per second
    }

    public function loadAllowance($request, $action)
    {
        return [$this->account->allowance, $this->account->allowance_updated_at];
    }

    public function saveAllowance($request, $action, $allowance, $timestamp)
    {
        $this->account->allowance = $allowance;
        $this->account->allowance_updated_at = $timestamp;
        $this->account->save();
    }
    
    // ... the rest of User class definitions ...
}
```

The second option is to have some other class implement `RateLimitInterface` and use closure in [`yii\filters\RateLimiter::$user`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-ratelimiter#$user-detail) to return instance of that class.

Comment: Thanks Michal. Your answer was part of the solution, so I'll mark it as correct.
The other problem I encountered was allowance_updated_at needs to be a Unix timestamp (ie. an int, not a datetime or timestamp). 
Still ended up having to call RateLimiter->checkRateLimit explicitly in my Api controller.

Comment: @RedTera the fact that allowance_updated_at needs to be unix timestamp is mentioned in documentation you've linked. It's weird that you have to call checkRateLimit by yourself. That method is called in `beforeAction` by the RateLimiter. You just need to have RateLimiter behavior attached to your controller and it must be attached after authentication behavior to make sure the user is already identified when the rate is checked. This is already done in `yii\rest\Controller`, if you are not extending it you have to set behaviors yourself.